# Error in tf.data.Dataset after splitting frame and label data

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, video-processing

I am working on video data load generator. Working with UCF-11 dataset at first I created a Frame_Generator where the code is:

```
def format_frames(frame, output_size):
  frame = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(frame, tf.float32)
  frame = tf.image.resize_with_pad(frame, *output_size)
  return frame 

def frames_from_video_file(video_path, n_frames, output_size = (224,224), frame_step = 15):
  result = []
  src = cv2.VideoCapture(str(video_path))
  video_length = src.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
  need_length = 1 + (n_frames - 1) * frame_step
  if need_length > video_length:
    start = 0
  else:
    max_start = video_length - need_length
    start = random.randint(0, max_start + 1)

  src.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, start)
  ret, frame = src.read()
  result.append(format_frames(frame, output_size))

  for _ in range(n_frames - 1):
    for _ in range(frame_step):
      ret, frame = src.read()
    if ret:
      frame = format_frames(frame, output_size)
      result.append(frame)
    else:
      result.append(np.zeros_like(result[0]))
  src.release()
  result = np.array(result)[..., [2, 1, 0]]
  return result


from pathlib import Path

class FrameGenerator:
  def __init__(self, path, n_frames, training=False):
      self.path = Path(path)  # Convert the string to a Path object
      self.n_frames = n_frames
      self.training = training
      self.class_names = sorted(set(p.name for p in self.path.iterdir() if p.is_dir()))
      self.class_ids_for_name = dict((name, idx) for idx, name in enumerate(self.class_names))

  def get_files_and_class_names(self):
    video_paths = list(self.path.glob('*/*.mpg'))
    classes = [p.parent.name for p in video_paths]
    return video_paths, classes

  def __call__(self):
    video_paths, classes = self.get_files_and_class_names()

    pairs = list(zip(video_paths, classes))

    if self.training:
      random.shuffle(pairs)

    for path, name in pairs:
      video_frames = frames_from_video_file(path, self.n_frames)
      label = self.class_ids_for_name[name] # Encode labels
      yield video_frames, label

output_signature = (tf.TensorSpec(shape = (None, None, None, 3), dtype = tf.float32),
                    tf.TensorSpec(shape = (), dtype = tf.int16))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(FrameGenerator("E:/UCF11_updated_mpg", 10), output_signature=output_signature)

split = 3
train_ds = dataset.window(split, split + 1).flat_map(lambda *ds: ds[0] if len(ds) == 1 else tf.data.Dataset.zip(ds))
val_ds = dataset.skip(split).window(1, split + 1).flat_map(lambda *ds: ds[0] if len(ds) == 1 else tf.data.Dataset.zip(ds))

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size = AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size = AUTOTUNE)

train_frames, train_labels = next(iter(train_ds))
print(f'Shape of training set of frames: {train_frames.shape}')
print(f'Shape of training labels: {train_labels.shape}')
```

Now, the problem that I am facing that is, after splitting the training and testing set, to get the frame and label in training_set I am getting the below error:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-b54a67dddf98> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 train_frames, train_labels = next(iter(dataset_train))
      2 print(f'Shape of training set of frames: {train_frames.shape}')
      3 print(f'Shape of training labels: {train_labels.shape}')

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py in __next__(self)
    807   def __next__(self):
    808     try:
--> 809       return self._next_internal()
    810     except errors.OutOfRangeError:
    811       raise StopIteration

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py in _next_internal(self)
    770     # to communicate that there is no more data to iterate over.
    771     with context.execution_mode(context.SYNC):
--> 772       ret = gen_dataset_ops.iterator_get_next(
    773           self._iterator_resource,
    774           output_types=self._flat_output_types,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py in iterator_get_next(iterator, output_types, output_shapes, name)
   3026       return _result
   3027     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
-> 3028       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   3029     except _core._FallbackException:
   3030       pass

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   5886 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name) -> NoReturn:
   5887   e.message += (" name: " + str(name if name is not None else ""))
-> 5888   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   5889 
   5890 

InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_2_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 270, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/from_generator_op.py", line 198, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "<ipython-input-6-632c7dbb767a>", line 33, in __call__
    video_frames = frames_from_video_file(path, self.n_frames)

  File "<ipython-input-5-9689ec3a44cb>", line 30, in frames_from_video_file
    result.append(format_frames(frame, output_size))

  File "<ipython-input-4-08dd81b48055>", line 12, in format_frames
    frame = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(frame, tf.float32)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 102, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext] name:
```

How can I solve the issue or any suggestions! Thanks in advance..

Comment: printout the frame, see if it's an actual array or not because of invalid parse. (I would suggest to use decord for decoding video data.).